# IE6 - multiline textbox not scrolling more than 6 rows

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-6

I have some multiline text boxes that are acting up in IE6.
Here is the markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCOMMENTS" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4"></asp:TextBox>
```

The problem is that when the page loads, you can only scroll down to the bottom of the first 6 rows. i.e. at first you see the top 4, you can then scroll down 2 steps to see the 6th row. Any further rows are there but you cannot get to them.

If you hold the down arrow for a while to get to the bottom and then press return, you get to see and scroll all the text, so it's definitely all there.

I've tried all sorts of messing around with the properties of the control and css but cannot get this to work. Everything is fine in any other browser I try.

Comment: Ok, I must ask. IE6 is a superior and powerful browser, but in 2014 really? Is it a kiosk?

Comment: It's a limitation imposed by the client. It has to be IE6.

Comment: On the plus side, they are upgrading to IE8 soon... Yes, I want to cry.